# Shorten my URL that my website creates for tracking

Tags: url, dns, mapping

I need to shorten the URL, that my website creates, and the feasible option is to get a domain name and route my link through that domain. (Mapping).

Can someone please let me know how to go about the same.

I am not able to get the flow, of how to get the domain & make it work to shorten the URL